# jQuery Mobile Validation in Asp.Net MVC5

Tags: asp.net, html, jquery-mobile

I'm creating a jQuery Mobile based ASP.NET MVC 5 application utilizing the jQuery validation. Ealier validation was working fine but its stopped working suddenly. I am unable to find the reason.

Here is a sample of the code in use:

**Model:**

```
        [DisplayName("Select file(s) to upload")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Select atleast one file")]
        public HttpPostedFileBase File { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [StringLength(250, MinimumLength = 3)]
        public string Comments { get; set; }
```

**View:**

```
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.File, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.File, new { type = "file"})
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.File)
        </div>
    </div>
    <br />
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Comments, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Comments)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Comments)
    </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery files in generated HTML**

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.js"></script>  
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
```

Whenever I submit the form it always go to controller instead of performing client side validation and showing error messages.
Why?

Comment: is jquery files included which are essential for it, check console using web developer tools

Comment: See the edit. I have included jQuery files in generated HTML